# how to set anchor tag individual item to an array images

Tags: javascript, css

I added dynamic images display in specific div but I could not set link (a href)for each image individually.Could you help me?
Here is my script which I used but not working:

```js
<script>
var i;
var timerid = 0;
var images = ["img1.jpg",
            "img2.jpg",
            "img3.jpg","img4.jpg"];


var countimages = 0;
function startTime()
{
    if(timerid)
    {
        timerid = 0;
    }
    var tDate = new Date();

    if(countimages == images.length)
    {
        countimages = 0;
    }
    if(tDate.getSeconds() % 4 == 0)
    {
        document.getElementById("img1").src = images[countimages];
    }
    countimages++;
    timerid = setTimeout("startTime()", 800);
    switch(countimages){
        case images[0]: images[0].setAttribute('href',"dhow-cruise-creek-dubai.html");
        images[0].innerHTML="dhow-cruise-creek-dubai.html";
            document.appendChild(images[0]);
            break;
        case images[1]:  images[1].setAttribute('href',"dhow-cruise-creek-dubai.html");
        images[1].innerHTML="dhow-cruise-creek-dubai.html";
            document.appendChild(images[1]);
            break;
            case images[2]: images[2].setAttribute('href',"dhow-cruise-creek-dubai.html");
        images[2].innerHTML="dhow-cruise-creek-dubai.html";
            document.appendChild(images[2]);
            }

}
</script>
```

Comment: hi Vidya can I know you want to any action on this anchor tag ?? can you give me example in fiddle or else ??

Answer (score 1):

Several things here:

---

**1:** Your function is incrementing an array index (`countimages`) and wrapping it when it reaches the end of the index range of the array it is intended to subscript (`images`). You currently have two lines of code to accomplish this task, which are separated by another line of code. The two lines are

```
countimages++;
```

which is executed immediately *after* the subscripting of the aforementioned array, and

```
if (countimages == images.length) countimages = 0;
```

which is executed just *before*.

It would be much better, both for human readability and for code simplicity, to locate these two operations at the same spot in the code, because together they represent a single isolated and inseparable action. Also, the length cap can be applied more idiomatically and concisely using a modulus operation. The end result is you should delete the second line I showed above, and change the first to this:

```
countimages = (countimages+1)%images.length;
```

---

**2:** You are incrementing `countimages` in every evaluation of the function. This is happening even when the modulus test fails, and therefore the image is not changed. I suspect this is a mistake. Therefore I would change

```
if (tDate.getSeconds()%4 == 0) {
    document.getElementById("img1").src = images[countimages];
}
countimages = (countimages+1)%images.length;
```

to

```
if (tDate.getSeconds()%4 == 0) {
    document.getElementById("img1").src = images[countimages];
    countimages = (countimages+1)%images.length;
}
```

---

**3:** I don't see any point in zeroing the `timerid` variable at the start of the function. It will inevitably be overwritten by the return value of the `setTimeout()` call later in the function. So the statement

```
if (timerid) timerid = 0;
```

should be removed.

---

**4:** The [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) function supports two overloads. The first argument to the function can be either a *function reference* or a *string of code*. The former is preferable, both for performance and security reasons. So you should change

```
timerid = setTimeout('startTime()',800);
```

to

```
timerid = setTimeout(startTime,800);
```

But see below.

---

**5:** The [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) function is preferable to `setTimeout()` for a continuously repeating function call. Under this design, the function does not even need to reference `timerid`, or concern itself with its own invocation. We can just call `setInterval()` once during page load to start the chain of calls.

---

**6:** The switch statement at the end of the function is switching on `countimages`, which is of numeric type, against various elements of the `images` array specified by literal index, i.e. `images[0]`, `images[1]`, and `images[2]`. The `images` array holds string values representing image URLs, not numbers. So obviously this switch statement is incorrect. Also, the final element (`images[3]`) is omitted, which may be a mistake. If your intention was to switch on the indexes of the array, your case values should be `0`, `1`, etc. But see below.

---

**7:** Each of the case branches in the switch statement is identical to the others, except for the literal index. That is, they all follow this pattern, where `i` is the literal index:

```
case images[i]:
    images[i].setAttribute('href','dhow-cruise-creek-dubai.html');
    images[i].innerHTML = 'dhow-cruise-creek-dubai.html';
    document.appendChild(images[i]);
    break;
```

except that the final `break;` statement is missing from the final case branch.

This is an example of duplicate code that should be simplified by proper parameterization; in this case, parameterizing on `i`. Observe that the literal index always corresponds to the current value of `countimages`, so that is our `i`. In other words, the entire switch statement can be replaced with the following, again, assuming you wanted to switch on the indexes of the array:

```
images[countimages].setAttribute('href','dhow-cruise-creek-dubai.html');
images[countimages].innerHTML = 'dhow-cruise-creek-dubai.html';
document.appendChild(images[countimages]);
```

But see below.

---

**8:** The above lines of code are incorrect because they appear to be treating `images` as an array of elements, when it is in fact an array of strings. You cannot call [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) on a string, nor is there a meaningful [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property of strings, and you cannot append strings to the DOM tree using [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) (because strings do not implement the interface `Node`).

This brings us to your question. Your code seems to be trying to append a new anchor link element at the bottom of the entire document every time the image is advanced, but I doubt that's what you really want. I'm guessing you want to advance a single fixed anchor link element to a new `href` attribute and `innerHTML` content corresponding to the new image. To do this, I would recommend you change the array of strings to an array of hashes and store the `href` and `innerHTML` alongside the image URL using three key/value pairs.

---

**9:** The design of advancing the image and link during every multiple of 4 seconds, but checking for such a condition every 800 milliseconds, is very questionable. In some cases the check will be true twice in a multiple-of-4 second, in some cases it will be true only once during the multiple-of-4 second. And the moments the function is executed will drift, since the interval duration is not guaranteed to be exact. This would lead to some strange behavior. I suppose you may want this behavior, but I'm doubtful. Instead, I suspect what you're going for is for the image and link to advance once every 4 seconds. You can achieve this by removing the entire time test and just setting the interval to 4 seconds, that is, 4000 milliseconds.

---

Hence, we have:

```js
var imageSpecs = [
    {imageURL:'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8062178f34c7107a67ef00b681921287?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1',linkRef:'#1',innerHTML:'one'  },
    {imageURL:'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b57bf879dbb25c837c2e2ae730cab2cc?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1',linkRef:'#2',innerHTML:'two'  },
    {imageURL:'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/166ed38dafa219c53980bb06cfce40b6?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1',linkRef:'#3',innerHTML:'three'},
    {imageURL:'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0c8ea1549ebeff7bab9a282c4b965fa4?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG',    linkRef:'#4',innerHTML:'four' },
];

// preload all images
for (let imageSpec in imageSpecs) {
  let img = new Image();
  img.src = imageSpec.imageURL;
} // end for

var nextImageSpecIndex = 0;
function advanceImageSpec() {

    let imageSpec = imageSpecs[nextImageSpecIndex];

    let imgElem = document.getElementById('img1');
    imgElem.setAttribute('src',imageSpec.imageURL);

    let linkElem = document.getElementById('link1');
    linkElem.setAttribute('href',imageSpec.linkRef);
    linkElem.innerHTML = imageSpec.innerHTML;

    nextImageSpecIndex = (nextImageSpecIndex+1)%imageSpecs.length;

} // end advanceImageSpec()

var timerId = setInterval(advanceImageSpec,4000);
advanceImageSpec(); // immediate call to display first image immediately
```

```css
#img1 { width:100px; height:100px; }
```

```html
<div>
  <img id="img1"/><br/>
  <a id="link1"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, but I assume you want the image to be a link that goes somewhere. Try putting a link tag around the img element with id `img1` and giving that link tag the id `link1' like so:

```
<a href="" id="link1"><img id="img1"/></a>
```

Then change the script to this:

```
<script>
var i;
var timerid = 0;
var images = ["img1.jpg",
            "img2.jpg",
            "img3.jpg"];

var links = ["dhow-cruise-creek-dubai.html",
            "dhow-cruise-creek-dubai.html",
            "dhow-cruise-creek-dubai.html"];

var countimages = 0;
function startTime()
{
    if(timerid)
    {
        timerid = 0;
    }
    var tDate = new Date();

    if(countimages == images.length)
    {
        countimages = 0;
    }
    if(tDate.getSeconds() % 4 == 0)
    {
        document.getElementById("link1").href = links[countimages];
        document.getElementById("img1").src = images[countimages];
    }
    countimages++;
    timerid = setTimeout("startTime()", 800);
}
</script>
```

There's more that could be improved, but I'm sure you get where I'm going.